# "Hashes did not match" during deploying cookiecutter django with wagtail

Tags: django, docker, wagtail

I have been trying to deploy my Django/Wagtail project that is created with [Cookiecutter Django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/) using docker to a Digital Ocean droplet that I created using the command `docker-machine create`.The problem is that all the static files have the error `Hashes did not match` even after I use `./manage.py collectstatic`

I've tried to google it but cannot find any reference regarding this error.

```
django_1    | INFO 2019-07-28 10:24:52,920 etag 8 140528735497544 css/project.css: Hashes did not match
django_1    | INFO 2019-07-28 10:24:52,925 etag 8 140528735497544 images/favicons/favicon.ico: Hashes did not match
django_1    | INFO 2019-07-28 10:24:52,929 etag 8 140528735497544 js/project.js: Hashes did not match
django_1    | INFO 2019-07-28 10:24:52,932 etag 8 140528735497544 sass/project.css.map: Hashes did not match
django_1    | INFO 2019-07-28 10:24:52,936 etag 8 140528735497544 sass/project.css: Hashes did not match
```

Below is my static setting in base.py

```
# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR("staticfiles"))
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR.path("static"))]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Comment: Did you change your SECRET_KEY for deployment or are you using a compressor for static files?

Comment: What makes you believe that this is an error, rather than a harmless log message - is anything failing on your site, for example? The INFO part of the log message indicates that this is an informational message - it would say ERROR for an error condition. Additionally, googling has led me to https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast/blob/master/collectfast/etag.py#L120 which shows that this message is part of the normal operation of the 'collectfast' package.

Comment: @zypro no I didn't change my SECRET_KEY nor use compressor for static files

Comment: @gasman the reason is because the static files is not showing when I view the website. I just assume the information is the cause

Comment: @WilliamTekimam, did you find the solution? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @DAKZH Sorry, I just saw this. Turns out I misconfigured my traefik `.toml` file and once I fixed that, there are no more errors